# Derivate of vector : transpose, conjugate and conjugate transpose

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, transpose

Let $x$ and $y\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times 1}$ and $H\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times K}$ a diagonal matrix.

$\bar{x}$ denotes the complex conjugated, $x^{T}$ denotes the transpose and $x^{*}$ denotes the complex conjuguate transpose $x^{*}=\bar{x}^{T}$.

What are :

- $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{*}Hx$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{T}Hx$ ?
- $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{*}Hy$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{T}Hy$ ?
- $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{*}H\bar{x}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{T}H\bar{x}$ ?
- $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{*}H\bar{y}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^{T}H\bar{y}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: TY, this level of mathematical is recent to me.. is my formulation wrong or I miss something obvious ?

Comment: I don't think you can take a derivative with respect to a vector, at least not in some canonical way.  There is notation in vector calculus for related operations, but I think the notation is different, and you have to be more explicit with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the transpose, complex conjugate, and hermitian conjugates of $X$ as $(\,X^T,\,X^C,\,X^H),\,$ respectively.

Further, a colon will denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,\,A\!:\!B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

Now consider a single scalar function and its differential 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= z^THw = H:zw^T \cr
d\phi &= H:(dz\,w^T + z\,dw^T) \cr
 &= Hw:dz + z^TH:dw^T \cr
 &= Hw:dz + H^Tz:dw \cr
}$$
But since 
$$ d\phi
 = \bigg(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\bigg)\,dz
 + \bigg(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w}\bigg)\,dw
$$
we can identify
$$\eqalign{
  &\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} = Hw,\,\,\,\,\,&\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w} = H^Tz \cr
  &\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z^C} = 0,\,\,\,\,\,&\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w^C} = 0 \cr
}$$
Now substitute $\,z = \{x,x^C\}\,$ and $\,w = \{y,y^C,x,x^C\}\,$ to answer each of your questions.

Comment: That's exactely what I needed, thanks for the demonstration !